# Templates not loading in angularJS and Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I set up a basic ionic app with av few views and controllers. When I load the startpage I ALWAYS end up in `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('views/error.html');` line. And no templates gets loaded either.. even for the error.html.

I have no idea why. I get no js errors in the console or anything. Any ideas?

This is my code:

**the html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/MainMenuController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/SettingsController.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="iou">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**the javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('iou', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('mainmenu', {
        url: '/mainmenu',
        templateUrl: 'views/mainmenu.html',
        controller: 'MainMenuController'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        templateUrl: 'views/settings.html',
        controller: 'SettingsController'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('views/error.html'); // I always end up here
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for me was to change:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('views/error.html');
```

to:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

errors.html is in your views folder and has some markup to render? $urlRouteProvider.otherwise('directory/file.html') will always load first when your app starts up.

Comment: errors.html is in my views folder yes, and it has some markup. However, that markup doesn't get rendered. No markup does, the app just redirects to the error url but then it's blank..